# How to rebuild a $N\times N$ matrix from the sums of all of its submatrices of size $M\times M$ ($M\ll N$)

Tags: matrices

What I have is sums of smaller submatrices of size $M\times M$ ($M$ is much smaller than $N$, say $N/6$ or less). The sums of all possible submatrices at all positions are known. I am trying to rebuild the entire $N\times N$ matrix.

For example, if there is a $4\times 4$ matrix $X$ with the values

$$\begin{array}{cccc} 
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8\\
 9 & 1 & 2 & 3\\
 4 & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\end{array}$$

And I have the sums of submatrices of size $2\times 2$ (for all possible positions - assuming that the matrix is surrounded by infinite number of zero values).

The first known submatrix sum would thus be $0+0+0+1=1$:
$$\hskip-0.3in \begin{array}{ccccc} 
\fbox{$\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{matrix}$}\!\!\!\! & {\atop 2} & {\atop 3} & {\atop 4}\\
 \begin{matrix} \hphantom{0} & 5\end{matrix}\!\!\!\! & 6 & 7 & 8\\
 \begin{matrix} \hphantom{0} & 9\end{matrix}\!\!\!\! & 1 & 2 & 3\\
 \begin{matrix} \hphantom{0} & 4\end{matrix}\!\!\!\! & 5 & 6 & 7\\
\end{array}$$

...and the second submatrix sum, $0+0+1+2=3$:

$$\begin{array}{cccc} 
\fbox{$\begin{matrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 2\end{matrix}$}\!\!\!\!\!\! & {\atop 3} & {\atop 4} \\
 \begin{matrix} 5 & 6\end{matrix}\!\!\!\!\!\! & 7 & 8\\
 \begin{matrix} 9 & 1\end{matrix}\!\!\!\!\!\! & 2 & 3\\
 \begin{matrix} 4 & 5\end{matrix}\!\!\!\!\!\! & 6 & 7\\
\end{array}$$

The third sum would be $5$, the fourth $7$, and so on for each row and column in $X$. There are $(N+1)\times(N+1)$ of these sums, and they can be written as the matrix $Y$ (containing all available submatrix sums):

$$\begin{matrix} 
1 & 3 & 5 & 7 & 4\\
6 & 14& 18&22 & 12\\
14 & 21 & 16&20 & 11\\
13 & 19& 14& 18&10 \\
4 & 9& 11&13 & 7
\end{matrix}$$

The question is, how to rebuild / calculate the original $N\times N$ matrix $X$ from the $(N+1)\times(N+1)$ matrix $Y$, from the available submatrix sums? If it is not possible to calculate exactly, how well can it be approximated?

Any hints are appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wait a minute, if your matrix is padded with infinite zeros, then this is really easy.

You have
$$Y(i,j) = \sum_{\substack{i'=0\text{ to }M-1 \\ j'=0\text{ to }M-1}} X(i-i',j-j'),$$
so
$$X(i,j) = Y(i,j) - \sum_{\substack{i'=0\text{ to }M-1 \\ j'=0\text{ to }M-1 \\ (i,j) \neq (0,0)}} X(i-i',j-j').$$
That just says that for any $M\times M$ submatrix, you can find the value at the bottom right corner if you know all the other entries.

So start with the upper left corner: clearly, $X(1,1) = Y(1,1)$ because all the rest of the entries are zero as they are outside the $N\times N$ matrix. Now that you know $X(1,1)$, you can find $X(1,2) = Y(1,2) - X(1,1)$, and then $X(1,3) = Y(1,3) - \ldots$, and thus fill in the whole first row of $X$. Then you do the same thing, marching down the rest of the rows, and you're done.

Comment: Well, what can I say :-) Tamas, I suggest you accept this answer instead of mine; I was using a sledgehammer to crack a nut...

Comment: Thanks Rahul! Thats very useful. Would you also know a solution (or an approximation) in case there are unknown values around the matrix X, instead of zeroes?

Answer (score 3):

You have effectively applied a [box blur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur) filter. This is diagonal in Fourier space, so you can undo it by performing a Fourier transform, dividing by the filter's frequency response, and transforming back. For that to work, you need to choose a transform size such that none of the Fourier modes is annihilated by the filter (else you can't reconstruct them). This will be the case e.g. if the transform size is a sufficiently large prime. Since I don't know how much you already know about these things, I'll stop here; feel free to ask if any of that isn't clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick reply, joriki! A few questions: What is a filter frequency response? Is the size of the submatrices M the transform size? And finally, do you have a website or paper where I can read up on the subject? (Unfortunately I know little about this stuff...)

Comment: @Tamas: This looks like it contains a lot of what you might want to read up on: http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~jepson/csc2503/linearFilters.pdf. The frequency response is the (complex) factor by which the filter multiplies each of the Fourier components. No, the transform size must be at least $N+1$, plus some padding to avoid artefacts from the periodicity (I think $2$ or $3$ should be enough in this case; just increase it until the result doesn't change), plus potentially some padding to avoid one of the Fourier modes being annihilated by the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the pdf, joriki, it certainly helped - however, its still not clear to me how i can do this in my case, the case of oversampling (as far as i have understood the aliasing and area sampling reconstruction in the pdf, and in other sources i have looked at, they only work with undersampling, since that is the case in an overwhelming majority of image processing and similar applications). Could you maybe provide a short approach about how i could apply fourier analysis to this problem with oversampling? (Sorry if there was something in the pdf addressing that which I have overlooked...)

Comment: @Tamas: I think all of this has been superseded by Rahul's much simpler solution, but if you're still interested anyway: There's no question of over- or undersampling; you're not sampling. You have some data, and you transform them to Fourier space and then back -- the Nyquist theorem theorem doesn't enter into it; all you have to make sure is that you have enough padding so the two boundaries of the matrix don't interact with each other, and that you choose a transform size that doesn't cause one of the Fourier modes to be annihilated; in the $2\times2$ case, that means the transform size...

Comment: ... should be odd. So the recipe is basically: Choose appropriate transform size (in the example above, $7$ should be good), DFT in $x$ direction, DFT in $y$ direction, divide by the filter's frequency response, inverse DFT in $y$ direction, inverse DFT in $x$ direction. I linked to a PDF that concentrated on image manipulation because I thought it would have the most appropriate stuff for your 2D calculations (instead of 1D in music or 3D in solid state physics, for example), but some of that image-related stuff isn't relevant here. This is just about transforming to eigenmodes of the filter.

Comment: Thanks, I think I got it now, I'll try that solution. Rahul's way is simpler but I think it is not possible in cases where the surrounding values are not zero and unknown...

Comment: @Tamas: If the surrounding values are not zero and unknown, you can't reconstruct the data by any method. You can see this as follows: You're applying a linear operator. Since you can reconstruct the $N\times N$ matrix from the $(N+1)\times(N+1)$ result (assuming surrounding zeros), the image of the operator has full dimension $N^2$, and thus codimension $(N+1)^2-N^2=2N+1$. On the other hand, the surrounding values can change the values on the boundary arbitrarily, and there are $4N$ of those. It follows that you can get the same result for different matrices and different surrounding values.

Comment: A more concrete way of seeing the same thing: You can have a checkerboard of $1$s and $-1$s as input. The resulting output (assuming surrounding zeros) will be zero in the interior and on the margins and non-zero only at the corners. If the surrounding values are not zero, they could produce the same pattern on the boundary, so in that case you couldn't distinguish this input from an all-zero input.